# What is the meaning of this directory

Tags: html

When going to a directory above I do,

../

And when entering I do

/

But I also see this what does it mean?

./

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more detail into this question. There is not much to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`./` means "the current directory"

Comment: Oh that simple thanks, I tried searching it on google but it emitted it from the search so I had to ask on here!

Answer (score 1):

The three dir names you are talking about are unix-style directories.

The "./" is the "Current directory", also referenced simply as "."

The "../" is the "parent directory" (the directory before the current one), also simply ".."